# Java REST server the enterprise way

Tags: java

I have a web app that uses a PHP backend. The server gets requests and sends back data in json. In that sense its a simple REST server.
I want to reimplement the server in Java. What technology/framework should I use. More like, how will an enterprise solution look like?

Comment: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is of poor quality. You can get this by simple google search

- Spring (Spring Boot: Latest light weight one of spring)
- Struts
- Play
- SparkJava
- Dropwizard

And so on are popular java frameworks... Each has its own advantage. Where spring is the strongest and vast one. I would suggest Spring if its a heavy application. Else you can go for any of them.

See [this](http://viswanathl.in)

All of them are REST supported

Comment: I actually asked the question because I intended starting with spring but saw some negative reviews about it. I wanted to know if its possible to skip using any frameworks altogether

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu All the frameworks have its own advantages and disadvantages. Go ahead with spring, :)

Comment: Ok. Tnx for the suggestion then. Also, I read that spring is based on jsp and servlet. I dont need any view technology. My app is an spa written purely in js. Can I implement a minimalistic REST server in spring?

Comment: Go for Spring BOOT. Spring can serve alone for REST as well